# Image to vector of points

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to calculate the covariance of a multichannel image patch (using [cv::calcCovarMatrix](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#calccovarmatrix)), so I can in turn calculate the [Mahalonobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) of a pixel from that patch and I'm really struggling to find the right options to reshape the matrix into the right format.

For example if my matrix has 3 rows, 4 columns, and 2 channels:

```
// Channel 1:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2

// Channel 2:
99 98 97 96
95 94 93 92
91 90 89 88
```

What I believe I need is to reshape the image into a shape with 3x4=12 rows and 2 columns (or its transpose):

```
// Desired result:
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2
99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 89 88
```

1. Is this the correct format for cv::calcCovarMatrix?
2. What parameters do I need for .reshape() to achieve this?

An example in code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Construct channel 1
    cv::Mat_<float> channel1 = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 4) << 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
                                                         5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0,
                                                         9.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0);
    std::cout << "Channel 1: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << channel1 << std::endl;

    // Construct channel 2
    cv::Mat_<float> channel2 = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 4) << 99.0, 98.0, 97.0, 96.0,
                                                         95.0, 94.0, 93.0, 92.0,
                                                         91.0, 90.0, 89.0, 88.0);
    std::cout << "Channel 2: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << channel2 << std::endl;

    // Merge together
    std::vector<cv::Mat> stack;
    cv::Mat merged;
    stack.push_back(channel1);
    stack.push_back(channel2);
    cv::merge(stack, merged);
    std::cout << "Merged:" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << merged << std::endl;

    // Reshape
    cv::Mat reshaped = merged.reshape(0,1).reshape(1); // <----Need help with this line
    std::cout << "Reshaped:" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << reshaped << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think answers to both of your questions are to be found here: docs.opencv.org Did you try it?

Comment: That's one of my most clicked links, and where I've linked the functions to. I know the input to calcCovarMatrix should be `Samples stored either as separate matrices or as rows/columns of a single matrix.`, and I'm currently trying to make sense of the suggestions at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape with no luck to try and satisfy that requirement. Is there a more specific location in the docs you think I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but looking at the docs and the calcCovarMatrix() implementation, you should do something like

```
cv::Mat reshaped = merged.reshape(1,1);
```

or

```
cv::Mat reshaped = merged.reshape(1,3*4);
```

It seems that calcCovarMatrix() can process both column matrices and row-matrices.

You can take a look at the code in `opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp`, line 2097

Comment: `.reshape(1,1)` produces the same problem I've been encountering: 1 row, 24 cols. However, `.reshape(1,12)` does work so thanks for that.